# iOS - What exactly does allKeys: return in an NSArray, and how to alphabetize?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to create an array of the keys from an `NSMutableDictionary`, and then sort it alphabetically.  What I've got right now is:

```
_currentItemsArray = (NSMutableArray *)[_currentItemsDict allKeys];
[_currentItemsArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

but it's throwing an exception.  Specifically:

```
-[__NSArrayI sortUsingSelector:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e54ddb0
```

My research is telling me that that means the values of `_currentItemsArray` aren't `NSString`'s.  But what else would they be, when the keys of the source `NSMutableDictionary` are `NSString`'s?

And either way, is this the best way to sort an `allKeys` array alphabetically?

Comment: You can't just cast something to another class and expect it to magically convert.  No programming language works like that.

Comment: @SrikarAppal Read the code, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not simply cast an NSArray pointer to NSMutableArray pointer. Your `currentItemsArray` may be an NSMutableArray, but no amount of (NSMutableArray *) casts can make NSArray mutable. You'll have to use NSArray methods:

```
NSArray *array =  [[_currentItemsDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(whatever)];
```

Comment: Thank you!  And an upvote for the Boromir reference.

Comment: Btw, I fully trust that what you say is true, but can you clarify something for me: the reason I tried to cast it that way is because I got an "assigning NSMutableArray from NSArray" warning, but when I put the `(NSMutableArray *)` cast in front just on a lark, the warning went away.  Is that an XCode issue, not being smart enough to recognize that I'm attempting something impossible?  Or is there some other reason why that would make the warning go away?  I'm only asking so I can avoid doing similarly pointless things in the future...

Comment: You'll just have to pay more attention. If AB is subclass of A, then all AB may be treated as A, but not all A can be treated as AB.

Answer (score 1):

The correct method for a `NSArray` is `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`.

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [_currentItemsArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSLog("%@", sortedKeys);
```

Answer (score 1):

`-[NSMutableDictionary allKeys]` returns an `NSArray`. The order of the items is not predetermined but it usually is alphabetical. Anyway, since the return value is an `NSArray` you cannot use `-sortUsingSelector` as this method is only available on `NSMutableArrays`. You should use another method like `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:]` instead.